# SQL Use Declare to Omit Where Clause Items

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services

Is there a way to exclude parts of a SQL Statement based on Declared Values?

For instance;

```
DECLARE @OnlyY as VARCHAR(1) = 'Y'

SELECT count(*) from main where IDATE > '2016-01-01' 

If @OnlyY = 'Y' THEN
    AND Qualify = 'Y'
END IF
```

In this case if @OnlyY isn't Y then the part in between the if/endif wouldn't happen at all.

The reason I need this is because I am porting an Access 97 application to .NET. In the Access 97 app there is a part that creates a temporary table and then generates a report from that table. The SQL involved is a huge set of if/then statements that remove data from the temporary table. I'm able to build the DataTable for viewing in a Datagridview. My issue is that I can't get a SSRS to have the same flexibility as .NET in the if/then statements.

So how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you can look into is `Dynamic SQL` in which you can dynamically change anything you would need.

```
 DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @SQL = N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main WHERE IDATE > ''2016-01-01'''

 IF @OnlyY = 'Y'
 BEGIN 
   SET @SQL += N' AND Qualify = ''Y'''
 END

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: This is what I was almost looking for. I had to put () around the '@OnlyY = 'Y' and change THEN to BEGIN and END IF to just END. Otherwise, thanks. I had no idea this was possible. Now I just have to shield it from an injection attack.

Comment: Welcome, typo on my part. The nice thing about this solution is you can dynamically continue to add to your `where` clause. The downside to this is the query execution plain isn't optimized at this point as it's dynamic and isn't cached, but allows for dynamically adding conditions as you would need.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM main 
WHERE IDATE > '2016-01-01' AND 
      ((Qualify = 'Y') OR (@OnlyY <> 'Y'))
```

If `@OnlyY` is not equal to `'Y'`, then the `WHERE` clause boils down to:

```
WHERE IDATE > '2016-01-01'
```

otherwise, `WHERE` clause becomes:

```
WHERE IDATE > '2016-01-01' AND (Qualify = 'Y')
```